# using cache with json\rest services in wso2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

with wso2esb 4.7.0 i deployed the following service to perform a proxy and expose the same json i get from a different server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="crmws"
       transports="http"
       statistics="enable"
       trace="enable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
         <cache id="c1"
                scope="per-host"
                collector="false"
                hashGenerator="org.wso2.caching.digest.DOMHASHGenerator"
                timeout="6"
                maxMessageSize="10000">
            <implementation type="memory" maxSize="10000"/>
         </cache>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://crm/backoffice/webservice.php" format="rest">
                  <timeout>
                     <duration>3000</duration>
                     <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                  </timeout>
               </address>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <cache id="c1" scope="per-host" collector="true"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

i then try to implement some cache functionality, but even if first connection goes well, when i hit cache i get an empty answer with text/xml content-type.

**UPDATE 20131204**
I try again after 4.8.0 release and then enabling cache i get the full representation of my json in xml when i hit cache

anyone know where i have to look to fix this issue?
regards,

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following property in your insequence.

eg:

```
 <inSequence>
     <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
---------------------------
```

Comment: this doesn't help solving the issue, still getting an empty xml when the service hit cache, even if i use
`<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>`
in the inSequence to force the service to use this messageType